# Not just a word, what am I?

Tags: riddle

My first is in **donut** and also in **dough**
My second in **grew**, but never in **grow**
My third is in **famine** but never in **meat**
My fourth is in **sofa** but never in **seat**
My fifth is in **soldier**, but never in **sarge**
My sixth is in **flabby** and also in **large**
My seventh in **twentieth**, not **twenty-third**
My whole helps with hearing before sounds are heard.

Hint:

> There isn't a mistake with my seventh.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The poem refers to

> the notes of the [solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge):
>
>  My first is in **do**nut and also in **do**ugh
>  My second in g**re**w, but never in grow
>  My third is in fa**mi**ne but never in meat
>  My fourth is in so**fa** but never in seat
>  My fifth is in **sol**dier, but never in sarge
>  My sixth is in f**la**bby and also in **la**rge
>  My seventh in twen**ti**eth, not twenty-third
>
>  **Do Re Mi Fa Sol La Ti** (Do) = 1 octave
>
>   According to Wikipedia, "The study of solfège enables the musician to audiate, or mentally hear, the pitches of a piece of music which he or she is seeing for the first time and then to sing them aloud."

Comment: While the answer make sense in english, it's confusing to me. We use 'si' rather then 'ti' in dutch. (weirdly, the 'si' seems common for roman languages, while dutch is a german language... *shrugs*)

Comment: I understand where does Si come from. But... where does Ti come from?

Comment: Here in Brazil we use Si too...

Comment: Si was changed to Ti so that each syllable could start with a different letter.  That makes shorthand notation possible.  But where _does_ Si come from?  I know the origin of the first six syllables from the hymn Ut Queant Laxis, but "Si" is unrelated so far as I can tell.   No help from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Origin

Comment: @dennisdeems **Si** [comes from the next line of the same hymn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ut_queant_laxis) (**S**ancte **I**ohannes = *Saint John*), but was added later.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I suspected that might be the case, but hoped I was wrong.  To be sure, much later indeed!  No one needed a seventh scale degree until the 17th century :)